# Google Chrome extension to order recipients' email addresses in alphabetical order

Tags: chrome, gmail

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can order recipients' email addresses in alphabetical order.

E.g.

[image]

should be reordered as:

[image]

Here the ordering is based on the name, but I don't mind if it's based on the email address.

I use Google Chrome with Windows 7.

The best solution I can think of right now is writing an AHK script and bind it to a shortcut, which I would have to trigger each time I sent an email, which is a bit tedious.

Comment: If anyone has any idea

Comment: please add an answer.

Comment: I haven't found anything so far.